# How to display results in order of number of keywords matched?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Thanks to a fantastic video on youtube which you can access [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdM2ZIG9yR0) if you wish, I was able to create a php search engine. Below is the code:

```
<?php


//connected to DB

      foreach (array('questioncontent') as $varname) {
        $questioncontent = (isset($_GET[$varname])) ? $_GET[$varname] : '';
      }

?>

<form action="previousquestions.php" method="get">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo $questioncontent; ?>" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>

<?php 

if (isset($_GET['searchQuestion'])) {

$searchquestion = $questioncontent;
$terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

              $questionquery = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE ";

              foreach ($terms as $each){
               $i++;   

               if ($i == 1){
               $questionquery .= "QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ";
          } else{
               $questionquery .= "OR QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ";

              }

          }

      $questionnum = mysql_num_rows($questionresult = mysql_query($questionquery));

        else if($questionnum !=0){

      $output = "";
$output .= "
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      </tr>
";
        while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_array($questionresult)) {
$output .= "
      <tr>
      <td>{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

  }

}

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Now I have a question about how if possible can the results from the search be ordered. Lets say in the database I have these 3 statments:

```
My name
My name is Mayur Patel
My name is Patel
```

Now lets say I enter in the search box "name Mayur Patel", I want the results to be ordered so that it first displays any row which contains all of these key words, then after all of those rows have been displayed then display those rows which contains partial amount of those keywords (knocking a key word off one by one), so that the results of the search would be displayed in this order below:

```
My name is Mayur Patel (all keywords match in this phrase)
My name is Patel (2 keywords match this phrase which are 'name' and 'Patel')
My name (1 keyword match this phrase which is 'name')
```

I want to know if its possible if I can order the results of the search depending on the number of keywords that are matched within the phrases in the database?

Comment: @danihp: How is wanting to learn by watching a youtube video and extending the idea an indication that this is homework?

Comment: @mellamokb, sorry about this, but in my opinion create a search engine in this way should by for learning purposes only. It is not?

Comment: @danihp: sure, but I wouldn't call that *homework*.  That conjures up an image that the OP is trying to get us to do his homework for him, which is not the case and tends to be criticized on SO.  But learning for the sake of learning is very welcome and most of us agree with doing that.

Comment: @mellamokb, ops, sorry abut my obtuseness.

Comment: @danihp: No problem, resolved by a little civil discussion, as it should be :)  Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your query built in code looks something like this once it's completed:

```
SELECT * FROM Question WHERE
QuestionContent LIKE '%name%'
OR QuestionContent LIKE '%Mayur%'
OR QuestionContent LIKE '%Patel%'
```

To get the result you are looking for, you could add a sorting clause like the following, which would be generated in a similar manner from the list of keywords:

```
ORDER BY
IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%name%',1,0)+
IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%Mayur%',1,0)+
IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%Patel%',1,0) DESC
```

Basically it counts how many of the keywords are matching by saying if it matches, contribute one toward the keyword count, else contribute 0.  So in the end, this will yield 3, 2, 1 as the counts, and sort in descending order with `DESC` so entries with the largest number of matching keywords appear first.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaabc/2

---

**Edit:** As promised, here is a way to implement in the PHP code:

```
$questionquery = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE ";
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;   

    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ";
    } else {
        $questionquery .= "OR QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
}

$questionquery .= " ORDER BY ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;

    if ($i != 1)
        $questionquery .= "+";
    $questionquery .= "IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%',1,0)";
}
$questionquery .= " DESC";
```

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, you should show standard SQL rather than mysql specific-syntax.  The standard way of expression this would be:  (case when QuestionContent like '%name%' then 1 else 0 end) + (case when QuestionContent like '%Mayur%' then 1 else 0 end) + (case when QuestionContent like '%Patel%' then 1 else 0 end).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Not sure why that is relevant.  The OP is clearly using mysql and isn't asking for a general-purpose solution for all databases.  Also, the `homework` tag was edited in by another user, which I don't necessarily think was correct.

Comment: @mellamokb Hi, I know you answer suits the example I have provided but how is it written as a general query lke in my code? `"SELECT * FROM Question WHERE QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ... ";` Is it like this: `"SELECT * FROM Question WHERE QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%' ORDER BY IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%',1,0) DESC"`?

Comment: @user1394925: Hi. Do you follow how the `foreach` logic works?  Walk through the step of logic that is building up the query, maybe with pencil and paper, jot down what the query looks like during each iteration of the loop.  For each term, it is adding a piece of SQL to the query.  You will need to loop again through all the terms right below the first loop and add all the `IF(QuestionContent LIKE '%$each%',1,0)` to the query.  But you'll need a special case to add `ORDER BY` and `DESC` since those two keywords appear only once regardless of the number of terms.

Comment: If you still have trouble I can provide an example of how the PHP code would work, but I'd like you to give it a try first.

Comment: @mellamokb Well I tried what I commented to you but what that does is that it displays a result for 1 keyword but if I enter 2 keywords then it doesn't display any results. I will spend 10 mins trying to find this special case, if I can't figure it out then I will get back to you :)

Comment: @mellamokb, reading discussion I can see the mistake that my tag has  caused, sorry about this, +1.

Comment: @user1394925: I have added PHP sample of one way it could be implemented.  If you want to take your coding skills to the next level, I would recommend spending some time walking through the code line-by-line and trying to understand how and why it works.

Comment: @mellamokb Thank you for the answer. I would not of figured that out at all.  tried using a CASE statement with a THEN WHEN and ELSE clause but that was completly different from the theory you have shown. Thank you very much and I have commented the code you have given me in the application to be able to understand and use in future. Thank you very much :) +1 and best answer

Comment: btw, Using a `CASE` statement would work perfectly fine as well.  There are usually many ways to approach the same problem.  Glad to help and good luck!

Comment: @mellamokb, I think that you should warning about this poor performance solution.

Comment: @danihp: Agreed, this will not be the path to a real search engine without learning a lot about indexing, fulltext searching, caching, scaling, custom data storage, etc.